# d3 remove text from svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have sliders that modify the S command of a path. I want the source name to appear on the path which it does; however how do I remove the previously created text element?  I have tried to remove it (see code below) but it doesn't work. The dom just fills up with extra text elements and the text on the path gets darker and darker as they start to pile up on each other.  I have even tried to check for the text element by id as shown but no go.  Hope you can shed any light on how to remove the text element so there is just one as each S command is modified.

I have added a fiddle here (append text at very bottom of code window): 
[fiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/eformx/pnh05au0/)

```
graph.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
        //console.log(obj[0].text, graph.links[i].source.name, graph.links[i].linkid);

        if (graph.links[i].source.name == obj[0].text) {

            var linkid = graph.links[i].linkid;
            var the_path = $("#" + linkid).attr("d");
            var arr = $("#" + linkid).attr("d").split("S");

            //update S command
            $("#" + linkid).attr("d", arr[0] + " S" + scommand_x2 + "," + scommand_y2 + " " + scommand_x + "," + scommand_y);

            svg.select("#txt_" + linkid).remove();

            svg.selectAll("#" + linkid).data(graph.links).enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("id", "txt_" + linkid)
                .append("textPath")
                .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                    return "#" + linkid;
                })
                .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .text("")
                .text(graph.links[i].source.name);

        }
    });
```

Comment: A working example will be good, We can debug easily.

Comment: All I need is how to remove the svg text element, the best practise is what I am looking for...I have scoured the internet for the solution and most were svg.select("#txt_" + linkid).remove(); however that doesn't work.

Comment: @Rob, if you'd provide a working example, you'd get a response much faster, as it is easier for others to debug concrete code than to hypothesize what does not work based on your code snippet alone. There are a wide variety of places where you can create a simple working solution: jsfiddle, plnkr, jsbin, codepen, to name a few.

Comment: You're obviously selecting the wrong this as that ( svg.select("#idHere).remove();) should work. I notice you have two appends and the second one is the one the text gets appended to so perhaps select the second one ? So ('#'+linkid) rather than ('#txt_'_linkid)

Comment: I added a fiddle. Texts pile up. Unable to remove them.  Basically the user gets to modify the S command and I will offer them the ability to include the text and then move it closer to the end of the path with an adjustable startOffset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/kx3u23oe/

I did a couple of things. First, you don't need to bind this text to data the way you did. Second, I move the variable outside the `update` function, with all the `append`:

```
var someText = svg.append("text").append("textPath");
```

Then I kept only this inside `update` function:

```
someText.attr("xlink:href", "#L0")
            .style("font-size", "12px")
            .attr("startOffset", "50%")
            .text("some text");
```

Comment: In the end this is similar to what I came up with, moved the append into a button for different offset percentages so I could move the text.  It's not perfect; but I'm on a deadline.  Thanks Gerardo for the effort.

Comment: Let's try to improve this, tell me what would be "perfect" for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a text element using 'remove' function. Here is a working code snippet for the same.

```js
var text = d3.select("body")
  .append("text")
  .text("Hello...");

setTimeout(function() {
  text.remove();
}, 800);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

By the way, the problem in your code is, you are iterating over each link (`graph.links.forEach(function (d, i) {`) and creates a text element for all links(`.data(graph.links).enter()`) in each iteration. This creates n*n number of text labels; where n is the number of links. So I assume your code should be as follows.

```
 svg.select("#txt_" + linkid).remove();
 svg.selectAll("#" + linkid)
    .append("text")
    .attr("id", "txt_" + linkid)
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
        return "#" + linkid;
    })
    .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
    .attr("startOffset", "50%")
    .text(graph.links[i].source.name);
```

Comment: Didn't work...I added a fiddle. Texts pile up. Unable to remove them.  Basically the user gets tot modify the S command and I will offer them the ability to include the text and then move it closer to the end of the path with an adjustable startOffset.